# How insert raw HTML to label?

Tags: html, laravel-4, label

Is there some easy way how put raw HTML tag to label? I have this:

```
{{ Form::label('firstName', 'First name <em>*</em>', array('class' => 'input_tag')) }}
```

and it produces:

```
<label class="input_tag" for="firstName">First Name &lt;em&gt;*&lt;/em&gt;</label>
```

BUT tag EM is not interpreted as it should be. What I want is:

```
<label class="input_tag" for="firstName">First Name <em>*</em></label>
```

Comment: What should be the correct html output?

Comment: This is correct HTML input but on site near input is "First Name <em>*</em>" not  "First Name * "

Comment: Note, the HTML produced is actually entity-encoded: `<label class="input_tag" for="firstName">First Name &lt;em&gt;*&lt;/em&gt;</label>` and not quite as stated above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I include html within a form label using Laravel Collective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638287/how-can-i-include-html-within-a-form-label-using-laravel-collective)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `sprintf` in a `macro` is much faster than redecoding:

```
Form::macro('rawLabel', function($name, $value = null, $options = array())
{
    $label = Form::label($name, '%s', $options);

    return sprintf($label, $value);
});
```

Comment: If you only need this once and you want a quick and easy solution, you can do it inline too, e.g. `{{ sprintf(Form::label('tncs', '%s', array('class' => 'control-label tncs-label')), 'I agree with the <a href="/terms">terms and conditions</a>') }}`

Comment: Yes, that would work, but even for 1 use solutions its still better to extract it out. It's ugly and difficult to understand.

Comment: Where would the appropriate location be for this "widget" if I want to use it in multiple Views? I would prefer to include it only once, not every time I will need it.

Comment: I would have placed it in the boot function of your AppServiceProvider. You will need to reference the full FormFacade and not its alias (e.g. `\Collective\Html\FormFacade::` not `Form::`)

Answer (score 13):

use `HTML::decode()`:

```
{!! HTML::decode(Form::label('firstName', 'First name <em>*</em>', array('class' => 'input_tag'))) !!}
```

Comment: That would work in this specific example, but do be aware that there may be other entities in the resulting label element that you don't want decoded.

Comment: This worked like a charm. You may need to use the {!! !!} instead of the {{ 
 }}. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function (macro) just like:

```
HTML::macro('raw', function($htmlbuilder) {
   return htmlspecialchars_decode($htmlbuilder);
});
```

in your view:

```
{{ HTML::raw(Form::label('input_firstname', 'Prénom <sup>*</sup>')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use raw html for form input and labels as I find it easier to read and use html5 attributes such as required and placeholder. This form is a good example of how to use raw html with Input::old which allows you to capture old input. https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/blob/master/src/views/login.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

For required inputs, instead of trying to add HTML into the label, I add a class, 'required-input' (or something).

Then I have the following CSS rule

```
label.required-input:before {
    content: ' * ';
    color: #f00;
}
```

This would work unless you are needing to have the <em>*</em> for screen readers.  But you can still add the required flag on the input.

Answer (score -1):

Got it, it's using the e() helper function that uses htmlentities() to format your labels and this is converting your tag to `&amp;lt;em&amp;gt;*&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt;`.

The quick and (very) dirty fix is to add this to your start.php or some other place before the first call to Helpers.php:

```
function e($value) { return $value; }
```

But this far from ideal.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the Form::label($name, $value, $attributes, $escape_html) takes a fourth parameter which tells it whether to not to escape html. It defaults to true. So if your expected result is an italic *, pass false as the fourth parameter.

Comment: Looking at the API documentation for Form::label, we can see that there is no fourth parameter to escape html. http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#171-188