# How to add a tag (span, small) to Laravel Form::label?

Tags: laravel-4

In Laravel 4.1, I want to echo:

```
<label for="name">Name <small>required</small></label>
```

This doesn't work:

```
{{ Form::label('name','Name <small>required</small>') }}
```

are automatically converted to code text…

Is there a way or do I have to skip Form::label and do it manually?

Comment: You can create a Form::macro. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613110/laravel-4-how-insert-raw-html-to-label)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How insert raw HTML to label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613110/how-insert-raw-html-to-label)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a Html tag inside another by Laravel one you should use HTML::decode.

Correct code :

```
{{ HTML::decode(Form::label('name','Name <small>required</small>')) }}
```

Comment: For Laravel 5.1+ users, the correct tag for 'HTML' and 'Form' will be the aliases for Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade and Illuminate\Html\FormFacade you have configured in your config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{!! Html::decode(Form::label('name','Name <small>required</small>')) !!}
```

Comment: This code looks (to me) *very* similar to that in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25401545/10871073). You should add some explanatory text, outlining the difference(s) and why your code is better.