# How to get the <i> in laravel's links

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to use the  with laravel's links.

My link looks like this

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('admin\MenusController@edit', 'Edit', array(), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'button')) }}
```

and I would like to have the  icon with it.

Something like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
{{ HTML::decode(HTML::linkAction('admin\MenusController@edit', 'Edit', array(), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'button'))) }}
```

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259216/how-to-add-a-tag-span-small-to-laravel-formlabel)