# Trying to get the delete button to show the icon

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to get the font awesome icon to show in my delete button in my laravel form.

Here is the delete button

```
{{ Form::submit('<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'role' => 'button')) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use Form::submit, the content is always escaped. You can use Form::button instead, which does not escape the content.

Your code can be tweaked to:

```
{{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'role' => 'button', 'type' => 'submit']) }}
```

Also make sure to set **type = submit** while using Form::button.

Comment: Work for me on Laravel and Collective 5.2

Answer (score 1):

```
    {{Form::button(' Se connecter<i class="fa fa-key icon-on-right"></i>', array(
                        'type' => 'submit',
                        'class'=> 'pull-right btn btn-primary',
                        ))}}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some notes to explain how this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243840/how-to-get-the-i-in-laravels-links/26251286#26251286).

Basicly laravel allows to decode any html with `{{HTML::decode(<insert Form button here>) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the form builder is always going to escape it's content. Furthermore, the submit input type only supports text content, not HTML. You need to use a button element to display HTML content.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Delete</button>
```