# Laravel use html as anchor text in HTML::linkRoute

Tags: html, laravel

I`m having a problem using laravel blade html helper do geenrate a link.
The thing that i want to do is to use html "" as the anchor body, and i want this html to be rendered. I am calling the link as follows:

```
{{HTML::linkRoute('admin.event.edit', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>', $event->id) }}
```

The problem is that the pages show this:

```
<a href="****/event/2/edit">&lt;span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</a>
```

The question is : How can i tell the HTML::linkRoute to parse the content of the anchor tag.

Thanks for the time.
If you need more information as in the comment section.
Best Regards,
Georgi.

Answer (score 5):

This would do the trick, but it's not beautiful.

```
{{ HTML::decode(HTML::linkRoute('admin.event.edit', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>', $event->id)) }}
```

You could also create a macro like in this answer: [laravel 4: How insert raw HTML to label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613110/laravel-4-how-insert-raw-html-to-label)

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. As soon as i can accept the answer, i will. Thanks again for the answer.