# Escaping double quotes in a href using php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple questions. I have this function using php laravel that outputs a clickable link.
This is part of the back end.

> ```
>   public function linkify($text){
>   //$text = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i', '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $text);
>    $text = '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> ';
>       return $text; 
>   }
>
>  foreach ($res as $row) {
>    $subject= $this->linkify($row['subject']);
>    $json['amps'][$x]['subject']= $subject;
>    $x++;
>   }
>  echo json_encode($json);
> ```

And this is the front end

```
{{#each amps}}
        <li class="message">
        <img src="/images/people/{{pic}}" class="chatpic" alt="">
            <div class="message-text">
                {{subject}}         
            </div>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
```

The problem is that instead of outputting a clickable link it just displays plain text. 
I also noticed that the link is wrapped with double quotes
Here is the source code from the console window

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The string will auto escape when you use those. Likely duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the proper bracket syntax to show unescaped HTML

```
<div class="message-text">
            {!! subject !!}         
 </div>
```

The standard brackets wrap your value in the htmlentities() method behind the scenes to sanitize user input.

Comment: I am currently using laravel 4.1.24, which does not support the syntax. Is there an alternative syntax? or do you know if laravel > 5 is backward compatible?

Comment: You will want to create a blade macro. Instruction are found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613110/laravel-4-how-insert-raw-html-to-label

Comment: I managed to solve this by using {{{ subject  }}} instead.
Thanks for the help though. I appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing `{!! subject !!}` use triple brackets instead `{{{ subject }}}`

<sup>Disclaimer : I'm writing Israel Gonzales's comment as an answer, as that's the first link I got from Google for my question and the accepted answer didn't resolve it for me, but his comment did.</sup>